# How to change supervisor name on Horizon dashboard?

Tags: laravel, horizon

I've checked the source code and it seems that the name is determined from the server hostname and some random 4 characters string. What's the proper way to set it programmatically?
Here's a sample: `myserver-UME9`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a custom `nameResolver` on `app/Providers/HorizonServiceProvider.php` as shown below:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

...
use Laravel\Horizon\MasterSupervisor;
...

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        ...

        MasterSupervisor::determineNameUsing(function() {
          return "my_fancy_name";
          // return "my_fancy_name" . config('horizon.supervision_name');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Old post but does this actually work? When I am trying the dashboard doesn't show any of the supervisors anymore.